# @EJB injection in a Custom UserdetailsService (implementing Spring Security UserDetailsService)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, spring-security, ejb-3.1

I'm using glassfish 3.1.2 in a JPA/EJB 3/JSF 2/Spring Security 3 in my application.
I want to write a custom UserdetailsService like this one:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyUserDetailsService.class);
        @EJB
        private CollaborateurFacadeLocal collaborateurFacade;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
            Collaborateur collab = getUser(userName);
            if (collab == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + " not found");
            }
            User user = new User(collab);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + " not found");
            }
            return user;
        }
    }
```

So I'm trying to inject an EJB in my MyUserDetailsService to be able to use it as an authentication provider in my Spring Security context file : "applicationContext-security.xml" like this :

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

The problem is that I'm falling in a NullPointerException caused by a null collaborateurFacade.

I tried several things, among them:

- Loooking up the EJB using the context (like the one sited [here](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2011/08/integrating-ejb3-session-bean-with.html)): solution works but this is not what I want : because the name of the EJB is subject to be modified.
- Putting the class MyUserDetailsService as a JSF 2 managed bean, the collaborateurFacade iss till null.
- Putting the class MyUserDetailsService as a JSF 2 managed bean and with an ApplicationScoped scope, the collaborateurFacade iss till null.

Question:
Is there any clean method to inject the EJB in the MyUserDetailsService class ?

I know that I can annotate my class with an @Service annotation (See [this link](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2012/01/spring-security-31-implement_3065.html)), and then I will fall in a mix of EJB and Spring which I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured to solve my problem by : not renaming my facade (EJB) and having to looking up to my EJB with a name that I define within the class annotation @EJB. Then my UserDetailsService becomes like this:

```
@EJB(name = "collaborateurFacadeLocal", beanInterface = CollaborateurFacadeLocal.class)
public class SiUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SiUserDetailsService.class);
    private CollaborateurFacadeLocal collaborateurFacade;

    private static final String COLLABORATEUR_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH = "java:comp/env/collaborateurFacadeLocal";

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) {
        User user;
        Collaborateur collab = getUser(userName);
        if (collab == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + " not found");
        }
        user = new User(collab);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(userName + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    private Collaborateur getUser(String userName) {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            collaborateurFacade = (CollaborateurFacadeLocal) initialContext.lookup(COLLABORATEUR_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH);
            return collaborateurFacade.findUserByUserName(userName);
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            logger.error("Could not lookup for EJB CollaborateurFacadeLocal with lookup path " + COLLABORATEUR_EJB_LOOKUP_PATH);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The collaborateurFacadeLocal in the java:comp/env/collaborateurFacadeLocal is the one in the @EJB(name = annotation, linking it with the attribute @EJB(name =

This way:

- If the facade name is changed, there will be a compilation error in my SiUserDetailsService and with only changing its name in my siUserDetailsService class, the lookup will still work.
- If the ear name changes, my SiUserDetailsService still works because I don't lookup with the ear name.

My Spring Security context file is still:

```
<beans:bean id = "siUserDetailsService" class = "com.xxx.xxx.beans.SiUserDetailsService" />  

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="siUserDetailsService">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example which **in theory** should work

1. Add it into your context configuration

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">  
    <property name=”alwaysUseJndiLookup” value=”true” />  
</bean>
```

2. I guess you have a local EJB since you try to use @EJB annotation. You have to give a mapped name to your EJB. For example for a stateless one use

```java
@Stateless(name = "ejb/CollaborateurFacade", mappedName = "ejb/CollaborateurFacade")
class CollaboratorFacade {}
```

3. Use mappedName in your spring bean

```java
@EJB(mappedName = "ejb/CollaborateurFacade")
private CollaborateurFacadeLocal collaborateurFacade;
```

I know you wrote that the name of EJB is a subject to be modified, but I don't see how you can avoid that the way you try to do it.

And there is another possible solution (xml based!) http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.ca/2012/05/how-to-call-stateless-ejb-from-spring.html

Comment: Do you mean the applicationContext-security.xml file when you say : context configuration, because further than this, I don't have any other spring config file.

Comment: Yes, add it in the applicationContext-security.xml

Comment: I keep getting Invalid bean definition with name 'ejb/CollaborateurFacade' defined in JNDI environment: JNDI lookup failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ejb/CollaborateurFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CollaborateurFacade not found]

Comment: When the EJB has been deployed you should see the JNDI string it was registered with, what it says?

Comment: It has the unportable JNDI name which contains the era name and the EJB name which is exactly wht I don't want. But figured to have a possible solution to my problem.. Printing it in an answer.

Comment: If you have time you can try @EJB(mappedName="collaborateurFacadeLocal") or "env/collaborateurFacadeLocal", just to have a bit cleaner solution.